# The functions fromNow() and toNow() from momentjs do not work as expected

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a strange issue with **momentjs**, I have a date come from API like this

```
 "created_at": "2020-10-31 14:58:54".
```

and I want to use `.fromNow()` so the expected result is for example `30 minute ago` as [Docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/) says.

But I got `in 30 minutes`.

and when I use `.toNow()` I got `30 minute ago` :D but here I should have get `in 30 minutes` instead as stated in the [Doc](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/tonow/)

Code snippet:

```
{moment(item.created_at).locale('en').toNow()} => 30 minute ago

{moment(item.created_at).locale('en').fromNow()} => in 30 minutes
```

Comment: Is the time in the same timezone as your system? log both `moment()` and `moment(item.created_at)` and compare manually to be sure.

Comment: @pilchard interesting, i will check the backend guy.

Comment: LOG: `moment() => "2020-10-31T12:42:34.473Z"
 moment(item.created_at) =>  "2020-10-31T13:39:04.000Z"`

Comment: well, `created_at` is after your current time (made in the future?), but since it is an hour difference (accounting for the time between creation and log I would guess) it would appear to be a timezone issue. It looks like your return values are accurate, if unexpected.

Comment: @pilchard yes, you're right, how can i set the timezone in this case, Client-side?

Comment: your backend API should return UTC time, try to compare it with `moment.utc()`. If you log `moment.utc()` what is the result?

Comment: @Andriy Actually yes, the problem was in timeZone, it's log `"2020-10-31T13:00:35.374Z"`